# RctEngine joinChannel with token generated from serve in ReactNative Agora

Tags: react-native, agora.io

from server i am getting channel name along with tokenwithuid and tokenwithuserac.
How to use these to let user join the channel.

As before from demo i was doing following steps

this._engine = await RtcEngine.create(appId)

added some event listeners

after that triggered below method
await this._engine ?.joinChannel(this.state.token, this.state.channelName, null, 1)

But with token and channel name from server i am getting error code 110.

Answer (score 0):

ERR_NO_AUTHORIZED(110) means an invalid token.
Possible reasons:

1. I can see you are using number uid to join the channel, so you need to pass the token generated with tokenWithUid and not tokenWithAccount function.
2. Reverify the customer certificate, app id, and channel name.
3. Make sure you set the expiry time dynamically inside the tokenWithUid function.